# Unity of Quotient rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I know that,  if ring does not have unity then quotient ring may have unity.

if possible then I need example of ring which does not have unity(multiplicative identity) but its quotient ring is field.

Further,
While reading a book of "Abstract algebra" by Dummit & Foote" I saw the result:
"Let be commutative ring then ideal M of R is maximal if and only if the quotient ring R/M is field" 
 But isn't it necessary that R must have unity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $R,I,J$ be given by
\begin{align*}
R &= Z_2[x]\\[3pt]
I &= (x)\\[3pt]
J &= (x^2 - x)\\[3pt]
\end{align*}

Then

- $I$ is an ideal of $R$, but also a ring without unity$\\[6pt]$.

  $J$ is an ideal $R$, but also an ideal of the ring $I$.

Now simply note that $I/J$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$, hence is a field.

Comment: Thanks! Very beautiful example. Showing what exactly I want. If possible can you tell me here J is the maximal ideal of I or not? I think J must be maximal because otherwise I/J will not be a field. Is am I right?

Comment: Yes, $J$ is maximal in $I$. Note that in $I/J$, the identity element is $x$.

Comment: @Akash: Your posted question was a good one. Don't lose the curiosity.

Comment: @Akash: You should try to verify that every element of $I$ can be reduced,  mod $J$, to either $0$ or $x$.

Comment: @Akash: Also, note that $J$ is defined as a principal ideal of $R$, but although $J$ is also an ideal of the ring $I$, it's not a principal ideal of the ring $I$.

Answer (score 0):

About the further

No, it is necessary that $R$ is unital. In fact, maybe it's also necessary that $R$ is nonzero. Both these assumptions are stated at the start of Chapter 7.4.

[image]